# Outputing classification probability from the Qiskit VQC

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

all. I would like to have the Qiskit VQC output the predicted probability of each class instead of outputing only the prediction.

I am new to Qiskit. For the last few days, I have been trying to train my first VQC to do some classification task. Now the VQC is successfully running but it could only output a label whenever I ask it to predict something using the "predict()" method listed in:

https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.VQC.html

However, I would like to have it output the probability of each class. In my case, I have two classes. So I am looking for an output like [p1,p2] where p1 and p2 are the probability of class 1 and 2.

The reason why I need this is that I would like to draw the ROC of the network.